# With Kubernetes and a Windows node, is there are way to access another pod process from a sidecar container?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, process, azure-aks

I've got some pods in my cluster that I would like to profile using a profiling app on demands. We decided to separate the main image (the profiled image) from the code to profile it since they have a different purpose. I've configured my deployment like this:

```
(...)
spec:
  shareProcessNamespace: true
  containers:
  - name: profiler-container
    image: profiler-image
  - name: profiled-container
    image: profiled-image
(...)
```

The problem is that when the profiler process tries to access the profiled process, it can't find it. [Looking at the kubernetes node changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-windows/116-windows-node-support/README.md#v1pod), it seems they currently do not support the `shareProcessNamespace` option on the pod spec to share the process informations between two container.

Is there another way to do this for a windows container?